# WordPress: First post full content, rest excerpts Type Theme

Tags: php, wordpress

Yes, I know this has been asked before and I have tried the various solutions offered from the other posts, but without success. I'm looking to have my most recent post show the full content, and then the rest only show excerpts. For some reason, the counter++ and first methods are not working. I am using the Type Theme from Design Lab.

Here is my index.php:

```
    <?php
/**
 * The main template file.
 *
 * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
 * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
 * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
 * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package Type
 * @since Type 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <?php
    /* Blog Options */
    $blog_layout = get_theme_mod('blog_layout', 'list');
    $blog_sidebar_position = get_theme_mod('blog_sidebar_position', 'content-sidebar');
    $post_template = type_blog_template();
    $post_column = type_blog_column();
    ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <div id="primary" class="content-area">
            <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

                <section class="row posts-loop <?php if ('grid' == $blog_layout) { echo esc_attr('flex-row'); } ?>">
                    <?php /* Start the Loop */
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="post-wrapper <?php echo $post_column; ?>">
                            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', $post_template ); ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </section>
                <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

            </main><!-- #main -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->

    <?php else : ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'none' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php 
    // Sidebar
    if ( 'content-sidebar' == $blog_sidebar_position || 'sidebar-content' == $blog_sidebar_position ) {
        get_sidebar();  
    }
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And here is my content-list.php (what my theme is pulling from):

" >

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <figure class="entry-thumbnail">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">                
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('type-medium'); ?>
        </a>
    </figure>
<?php } ?>

<div class="entry-header">
    <?php if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) { ?>
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <span class="cat-links"><?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></span>
            <span class="sep">/</span>
            <?php echo '<span class="posted-on">' . type_time_link() . '</span>'; ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
</div><!-- .entry-header -->

<div class="entry-summary">
     <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

I know I need to change the_excerpt(); to the_content();, but I can't get it to only work on the most recent post, and any time I try to put the code for the counter in where I think is the start of the loop... I get a syntax error.

I'm more comfortable in html & css... but I get the basics of php... I just.. yeah, am failing with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give this article a read -> https://www.nosegraze.com/featured-post-homepage/

The way you can do this is to look for the latest post and display that using the_content(); if the post is not the latest post it should display the_excerpt.

Hopefully, this makes sense.

Thought I'd update the answer too. Doesnt look like you're actually looking for the latest post yet so I threw something up in a gist real quick. It may not work cause I didnt test it but you get the gist of it(ha)

```
<?php 
  if ( have_posts() ) : 
  $i = 0; 
?>
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <section class="row posts-loop <?php if ('grid' == $blog_layout) { echo esc_attr('flex-row'); } ?>"

            <?php /* Start the Loop */
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

              if ( $i == 0 && ! is_paged() ) {
              ?>
                  <div class="post-wrapper <?php echo $post_column; ?>">
                    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', $post_template ); ?>
                </div>
              <?php
                } else {                
                      get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'none' ); 
                 }
               $i++; 
               endwhile; 
            ?>
        </section>
        <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: So I tried what that author is saying to do... however... it's still not recognizing the counter.

I'm not sure if I'm not putting the  `<?php $i = 0; ?>` & `<?php $i++; ?>` in the wrong places or what.

Comment: @RiniCS can you start a codepen or a gist or something with your updated code so I can see what you're doing?

Comment: @RiniCS can't reply to your above code cause reputation /shrug but from what I can see you still aren't checking for the first post. I 100% doubt this will work cause didnt test it but it will give you an idea

https://gist.github.com/JordanNZ/52c83902dfbec62c7826dfffe52201d0

Comment: I tried your gist... and I kept trying what that article said to do with the counter code... and it's still not working. I think I just have to give up for now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... So... here's where I've been editing the index.php ... because the content-list.php was working fine...

```
<?php
/* Blog Options */
$blog_layout = get_theme_mod('blog_layout', 'list');
$blog_sidebar_position = get_theme_mod('blog_sidebar_position', 'content-sidebar');
$post_template = type_blog_template();
$post_column = type_blog_column();
?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
```

```
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <section class="row posts-loop <?php if ('grid' == $blog_layout) { echo esc_attr('flex-row'); } ?>"

                <?php /* Start the Loop */
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                     <?php $postcount++; //add 1 to the post counter ?>

                    <div class="post-wrapper <?php echo $post_column; ?>">
                        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', $post_template ); ?>
                    </div>

                        <?php $i++; ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </section>
            <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php else : ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', 'none' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, yeah it looks like you're on the right track, but not quite there yet. First off, you'll need to create the initial postcount and set it to 0.

So in your index.php, do this:

```
<?php
/* Blog Options */
$blog_layout = get_theme_mod('blog_layout', 'list');
$blog_sidebar_position = get_theme_mod('blog_sidebar_position', 'content-sidebar');
$post_template = type_blog_template();
$post_column = type_blog_column();
$postcount = 0; //This will be the counter for which post it is. If it's 0, show the full post, if it's higher, show the excerpt
?>
```

Then, further down in the index.php, do this:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <section class="row posts-loop <?php if ('grid' == $blog_layout) { echo esc_attr('flex-row'); } ?>"

                <?php /* Start the Loop */
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <div class="post-wrapper <?php echo $post_column; ?>">
                        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', $post_template ); ?>
                    </div>

                 <?php $postcount++; //add 1 to the post counter ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </section>
            <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
```

Since your theme doesn't define wether to use the full post or just an excerpt in the index.php like the example on the tutorial linked above does, you'll need to change something else as well.

in your content_list.php, find this part:

```
<div class="entry-summary">
     <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

and change it to:

```
<div class="entry-summary">
     <?php 
          if ($postcount == 0) {
             the_content();                  
          }
          else {
             the_excerpt(); 
          }
     ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

That should do the trick I think.

I hope that helped. If not, let me know what error you're getting.

Comment: Copied that in exactly, and it just made all of the posts full posts, no excerpts. (which I'll leave up for now at adorkableme.com)